# ZK Method setInputmode not found for class org.zkoss.zul.Textbox

Tags: zk

I am trying to set the HTML5 tag inputmode for the textboxes in order to have the right keyboard to showup on mobile devices but I get this error

Method setInputmode not found for class org.zkoss.zul.Textbox

when I add :

```
<component>
    <component-name>textbox</component-name>
    <extends>textbox</extends>
    <property>
        <property-name>inputmode</property-name>
        <property-value>search</property-value>
    </property>
</component>
```

in the lang-addon.xml

I am using Zk version 9

UPDATE :
I seem to have missread the JavaDocs for TextBox and it does not support this method.

I there anyway to have a TextBox configured to open the right keyboard on mobile device in order to be able to trigger the OnOk() event ?
Like maybe using native xmlns marker ? I tried and did not succeed...

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The only component that has `inputMode` is `org.zkoss.zhtml.Input`.
Textbox doesn't support that attribute, that's why you get the error. Where do you see that textbox supports the attribute?

Comment: I put the wrong link in my question,  and of course this was the place I found this info... I remember having found a javadoc page showing that TextBox was a subclass of Input and therefore had the setInputMode method available... but now that I search for the same javadoc I find that it is TextArea, I must have missread the JavaDoc then...  My bad, sorry